# I got Exception System.StackOverflowException when i try to render Tree view in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a tree view. for render child view i call a partial control every time for child controls of a parents.

can someone tell me how i can do it then System.StackOverflowException not caused

```
  <ul class="children">
        @foreach (var v in vat)
        { 
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="@v.ID" />@v.Name
                </label>
            </li>
            if (cat.Child.Count > 0)
            { 
            @Html.Partial("xxxx/views/partials/Childcats.cshtml", cat.Child)
            }
        }
    </ul>
```

Comment: `StackOverFlowException` usually determines infinite recursive calls.

check your recursion end conditions. and provide your code sample ,,,

Comment: now see the edited again

Comment: I bet you got Proprty Name defined with circural reference like public string Name { get { return Name; } }

Comment: no mr. lukas it is public string Child who have same struct.

Comment: Can you show us Childcats.cshtml? Are you sure there are no cycles in your category structure? What does the stack look like when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code is circular reference - when some node in tree references earlier node (most likely reason). Other possibility - you used too deep tree and when you recurse: stack overflowed.

Comment: BTW, when you set -1, write a comment why.